# how to end connection in java socket with "good buy" message

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I build a client/server chat in java 
and i want to end the connection if one of the client or the server send a "good buy" message 
but that not what happened the connection still a live

**The code in the client side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String message;
        String recivedMessage = "h";

        Socket clientSoc = new Socket("127.0.0.1",9999);

        while(recivedMessage != "good buy") {
            System.out.print("Client : ");
            BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSoc.getOutputStream());
            BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSoc.getInputStream()));

            message = inFromUser.readLine();
            outToServer.writeBytes(message + '\n');

            recivedMessage = inFromServer.readLine();
            System.out.println("Server : " + recivedMessage);
            if (recivedMessage == "good buy") {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (recivedMessage == "good buy") {
            System.out.println("Connection end");
            clientSoc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

**The code in the server side:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TCPServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String Message;
        String recivedMessage = "h";
        ServerSocket welcSoc = new ServerSocket(9999);

        while(true){
            Socket serverSoc = welcSoc.accept();
            while(recivedMessage != "good buy"){
                BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(serverSoc.getInputStream()));
                DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(serverSoc.getOutputStream());
                recivedMessage = inFromClient.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client : " + recivedMessage);

                System.out.print("Server : ");
                BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                Message = inFromUser.readLine();
                outToClient.writeBytes(Message + '\n');
            }
            if (recivedMessage == "good buy") {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (recivedMessage == "good buy") {
            System.out.println("Connection end");
            welcSoc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend using a sockets library such as:  https://github.com/mirraj2/Jexxus

Comment: thanks ,i will use it in the future

Comment: 'Good buy'? Do you by any chance mean 'goodbye'? And why do you think you need to send anything? Closing the socket is sufficient, unless you're interested in detecting truncation attacks.

Comment: its just part of assignment 
"Connection between two sides should be closed when any side sends “ GOOD BYE”. [2 marks]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you haven't shared the output, I'm assuming everything else is working as expected.
For string comparison use : `equals`

```
recivedMessage.equals("good buy")
```

In java `==` operator compares reference for objects, not the value. `Equals` method compares object value.

Comment: thanks ,that what i wont 
it work very well